# MongoDB Getting all documents that have the same foreign key

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following sets of data : supposing this is a 'category' collection, each category has a parent 'category' and belongs to a 'section' which is another collection :

```
 {
     "_id": ObjectId("5379e61b086d83de218b4568"),
     "name": {
         "en": "Inactive accounts"
     },
     "parent": ObjectId("5379e61b086d83de218b4568"),
     "section": "ObjectId("5379d4f9086d835328a22fc8")
 }
 {
     "_id": ObjectId("5379e61b086d83de218b4568"),
     "name": {
         "en": "second category"
     },
     "parent": 0,
     "section": "ObjectId("5379d4f9086d835328a22fc8")
 }
```

etc......

I'm trying to get all categories in the same section : here is my php code :

```
$categories = $db->categories->find(array('section' => new MongoId($section)));
```

In this case it returns {} an empty result, while if used findOne it returns one document.

```
$categories = $db->categories->findOne(array('section' => new MongoId($section)));
```

I'm not sure if I missed something, I may change foreign keys to strings instead of ObjectId('')s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it , I was processing the response incorrectly. the code above was working but 'find' function returns 'Cursor' while findOne return array.